# Kivy UI crashes when using sockets to receive data (client.recv())

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, kivy, recv

**Hi, I'm building a net banking application for my computer science school project.**

For the app I'm using socket library to connect the Kivy client side to the database. So when I use client.recv() method in the client side the app freezes.

The app has a login page, once the user enters the login credentials, the username and password is sent to the server. The server verify's the credentials with the database with python-mysql connector and sends back the `first_name` of the user, which is displayed in the menu page. But since kivy builds all the screens at once i.e the login page and the menu page is created at the same time.The app freezes at `client.recv()`.

**Is there any alternative to receive packets with socket in kivy?**

Here is the problem:

```
    class MenuScreen(Screen):
    data = pickle.loads(client.recv(1024))
    return data
```

`client.py`

```
import time
from _thread import start_new_thread
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRoundFlatIconButton, \
    MDFlatButton, MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivy.clock import Clock

import socket, pickle

# SOCKET SETUP

# CONSTANTS
BUFFER = 1024
ADDR = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 9090

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((ADDR, PORT))

screen_helper = '''
ScreenManager:
    LoginScreen:
    MenuScreen:
    RegisterScreen:
    
<LoginScreen>:
    name: 'login'

    username: username
    password: password

    Image:
        source: 'G:/My Drive/Scripts/Projects/KivyGUI/backgroundLight.jpeg'
        
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:(1,1,1,0.7)
                
            Rectangle:
                pos: 500,200
                size: 275,400
    
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Login'
        font_style: 'H2'
        font_size: 50
        theme_text_color: 'Secondary'
        halign: 'center'
        pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.73}        

    MDTextField:
        id: username
        hint_text: 'Username'
        icon_right: "android"
        icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.6}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 250
        
    MDTextField:
        id: password
        hint_text: 'Password'
        helper_text: 'forgot password?'
        helper_text_mode: 'on_focus'
        icon_right: "android"
        icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 250
        
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Login'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.565, 'center_y': 0.4}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 250
        on_release:
            root.show_data(None)
            root.manager.current = 'menu'
            
    MDFlatButton:
        text: 'Register'
        theme_text_color: 'Hint'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.43, 'center_y': 0.4}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 250
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = 'register'

<MenuScreen>:
    name: 'menu'

    Image:
        source: 'G:/My Drive/Scripts/Projects/KivyGUI/backgroundDark.jpeg'        
        
    GridLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:(0,0,0,0.4)

            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
            
        
    GridLayout:
        size_hint: 0.4, 0.6
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.65, 'center_y': 0.5}
        spacing: 20
        padding_x: 0.8
        cols: 2
                
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: 'Profile'
            size_hint: 0.4,0.1
            font_size: 25
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: 'Transaction History'
            size_hint: 0.4,0.1
            font_size: 25
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: 'Send Money'
            size_hint: 0.4,0.1
            font_size: 25
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: 'Received Money'
            size_hint: 0.4,0.1
            font_size: 25
    
    FloatLayout:
        orientation: 'tb-lr'
        size_hint: 0.3,1
        pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'left': 0}
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:(1,1,1,0.7)

            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        
        Image:
            source: 'G:/My Drive/Scripts/Projects/KivyGUI/profileIcon2.png'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.7}
            size_hint: 0.7,0.7
            
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Welcome back,'
            font_style: 'H4'
            theme_text_color: 'Secondary'
            halign: 'center'
            pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.43}
            
        MDLabel:
            text: ''
            font_style: 'H2'
            font_size: 50
            halign: 'center'
            pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.36}
            
        # MDTextButton:
        #     text: 'Change profile pic'
        #     text_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
        #     pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
            
    GridLayout:
        size_hint: 0.7,0.1
        pos_hint: {'right': 1, 'center_y': 1}
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:(1,1,1,0.7)

            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        
    MDIconButton:
        icon: 'cog'
        pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.975, 'right': 1}

    MDIconButton:
        icon: 'account-off'
        pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.975, 'right': 0.97}
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = 'login'


<RegisterScreen>:
    name: 'register'
    
    firstname: firstname
    lastname: lastname
    r_username: r_username
    r_password: r_password
    email: email
    phone: phone
    
    Image:
        source: 'G:/My Drive/Scripts/Projects/KivyGUI/backgroundLight.jpeg'
    
    GridLayout:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        size_hint: 0.4,0.9
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: (1,1,1,0.9)
            
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Register'
        font_style: 'H2'
        halign: 'center'
        pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.82}
        color: 0,0,0,0.5
    
    MDTextField:
        id: firstname
        hint_text: 'First Name'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.4, 'center_y': 0.65}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 200
    
    MDTextField:
        id: lastname
        hint_text: 'Last Name'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.6, 'center_y': 0.65}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 200
        
    MDTextField:
        id: r_username
        hint_text: 'Username'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.4, 'center_y': 0.5}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 200
    
    MDTextField:
        id: r_password
        hint_text: 'Password'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.6, 'center_y': 0.5}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 200
        
    MDTextField:
        id: email
        hint_text: 'Email id'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.4, 'center_y': 0.35}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 200
    
    MDTextField:
        id: phone
        hint_text: 'Contact no.'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.6, 'center_y': 0.35}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 200
        
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'Next'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.6, 'center_y': 0.2}
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = 'login'
            root.retData(None)

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'Back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.4, 'center_y': 0.2}
        on_release: 
            root.manager.current = 'login'
'''

Window.size = (1280, 720)


class LoginScreen(Screen):
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def show_data(self, obj):
        print(self.username.text, self.password.text)

        client.send(pickle.dumps(['login', self.username.text, self.password.text]))

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    data = pickle.loads(client.recv(1024))
    return data

class RegisterScreen(Screen):
    firstname = ObjectProperty(None)
    lastname = ObjectProperty(None)
    r_username = ObjectProperty(None)
    r_password = ObjectProperty(None)
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    phone = ObjectProperty(None)

    def retData(self, obj):
        print(self.r_username.text,
              self.r_password.text,
              self.firstname.text,
              self.lastname.text,
              self.email.text,
              self.phone.text, sep='\n')

        client.send(pickle.dumps(['insertion', self.r_username.text, self.r_password.text,
                                  self.firstname.text, self.lastname.text,
                                  self.email.text, int(self.phone.text)]))


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(LoginScreen(name='login'))
sm.add_widget(RegisterScreen(name='register'))


class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Pink'
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Light'
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen


DemoApp().run()
```

`server.py`

```
import socket, pickle
from _thread import start_new_thread
import mysql.connector as mys

# SOCKET SETUP

# CONSTANTS
BUFFER = 1024
ADDR = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 9090

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((ADDR, PORT))
server.listen(5)


def receive(client):
    while True:
        info = pickle.loads(client.recv(1024))
        if info[0] == 'insertion':
            insertion(info)
        if info[0] == 'login':
            display(client, info)


def handle_client():
    print('[ONLINE AND READY!]')
    while True:
        client, addr = server.accept()

        print(addr[0])

        start_new_thread(receive, (client,))


# MySQL Connection
myconn = mys.connect(host='localhost', user='root', port=15000,
                     passwd='adis', database='bank')

mycur = myconn.cursor()

if myconn.is_connected(): print('\n•CONNECTION SUCCESSFUL•')


def insertion(dt):
    try:
        data = f'INSERT INTO users (username, password, firstname, lastname, emailaddress, phonenumber, balance) VALUES("{str(dt[1])}", "{str(dt[2])}", "{str(dt[3])}", "{str(dt[4])}", "{str(dt[5])}", {int(dt[6])}, 1000);'
        print(data)
        mycur.execute(data)

        myconn.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def display(client, info):
    try:
        query = "SELECT username, password FROM users"

        mycur.execute(query)

        rs = mycur.fetchall()  # Record Set

        if tuple(info[1:]) in rs:
            print(tuple(info[1:]))

        client.send(pickle.dumps(info[1]))

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


handle_client()
```

**Please help me out, I'm already late for submission.**

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: can you help me with this? Is there anything I need to add?

Comment: You don't want to add something, you need to remove all the ununcessary stuff. Do you need this image to explain your problem ? `'G:/My Drive/Scripts/Projects/KivyGUI/backgroundLight.jpeg'` Do you need to have multiple screens ? I don't think so. Remove them and people gonna help you when we will feel that you have work on it.

Comment: I suspect that you need to put the code `data = pickle.loads(client.recv(1024))` in a method of `MenuScreen` and call that method at the appropriate time.